# Proving diagonal principle for nets

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, nets

Problem 11D in Willard's General topology textbook states that:

> Diagonal principle) If $(x_i)$ converges to $x$ and, for each $i\in I$, a net $(x^i_j)_{j\in J_i}$ converges to $x_i$, then there is a diagonal net converging to $x$; i.e., the net $(x^i_j)_{i\in I,\,j\in J_i}$, ordered lexicographically by $I$, then by $J_i$, has a subnet which converges to $x$.

How do you prove this fact ?

---

Here's my progress:

Firstly I found the wording of the problem to be a bit tad too confusing -- here's what I understand:

> So we have a directed set $D$, and a net $N$ on $X$, and for each $x_\lambda \in N$, there's a directed set $D_\lambda$ and $N_\lambda$ on $X$ such that it converges to $x_\lambda$. Define a new directed set $D' = \{ (i, j_i) | i \in D, j_i \in D_i \}$ such that $(\lambda_1, \mu_{\lambda_1}) \leq (\lambda_2, \mu_{\lambda_2})$ iff $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2$ and $\mu_{\lambda_1} \leq \mu_{\lambda_2}$ and the new net $N' = \cup_{x_\lambda \in N} N_\lambda$ such that if $i \in D$ corresponds to $X_i \in X$, and $j_i \in D_i$ corresponds to $X_{j_i} \in X$, then $(i,j_i) \in D'$ corresponds to $X_{j_i}$.
>
> We wish to find a subnet of $N'$ such that it converge to $x$ (the original net $N$ converges to $x$)

Let $\mathfrak{U}$ be the collection of open sets around $x$. Define a function $f: N \mapsto P(\mathfrak{U})$ as follows: $f(x_\lambda) = \{ U \in \mathfrak{U} | x \in U, \lambda \leq \lambda' \Rightarrow x_{\lambda'} \in U \}$. On the other hand, each $U \in f(x_\lambda)$ is an open set containing $x_\lambda$ too, so by the convergence of $N_\lambda$, we can define a function $g_\lambda: f(x_\lambda) \mapsto D_\lambda$ such that if $g_\lambda(U) \leq \mu$, then $x_\mu \in U$. Now it would have been nice to define $\displaystyle h_\lambda > g_{\lambda}(U) $ for all $U \in f(x_\lambda)$, and let $D'' = (\lambda, h_\lambda)$ and take $N''$ to be correspodning subnet induced by $D''$.

But the problem here is that $h_\lambda$ may note be defined when $|f(x_\lambda)|$ is infinite, and this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: You misunderstand the lexicographic ordering, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas to put you on the right track:

The directed set Willard describes from the directed sets $(I, \le_I)$ and the family of directed sets $(J_i, \le_{j_i})$, $i \in I$ (I'll forget about the subscripts on $\le$ in the sequel if they're clear from context) is rather:

$D'=\{(i, j): i \in I, j \in J_i\}$ with order

$$(i,j) \le (i',j') \iff i < i' \text{ or } (i=i' \land j \le j')$$

so lexicographically, where the $i$ decides the order first (if $i \neq i'$), and next (if they're equal) the order in the $J_i$ (to which then both $j,j'$ must belong by definition). Fact to check: $D’$ is in fact a directed set too. Quite easy to see.

If we have a net $f: I \to X$ and for each $i \in I$, nets $g_i: J_i \to X$, where $x \in \lim_i f$ and $f(i)=x_i \in \lim_j g_i$, we can define a diagonal net $h: D' \to X$ by

$$h(i,j) = g_{f(i)}(j)$$

And we need a subnet of $h$ that converges to $x$, so
it suffices to show that $x$ is a cluster point of $h$ (by Willard's theorem **11.5**) Can you show that? It's quite straightworward from the definitions.

Comment: Suppose $(i, j)$, $(i', j')$ and $(i'', j'')$ are points in $D'$ with $i < i'$ and $i' < i''$ then how would one prove that $(i, j)\leq (i'', j'')$? I was only able to conclude that $i\leq i''$. However, if $i = i''$ it is not clear to me how one would show that $j\leq j''$. Could you provide a hint to show this?

Comment: @KarthikKannan that's immediate from the definition of the lexicographic order. $j \le j''$ is not needed, unless $i=i'=i''$.

Comment: @Henro, could you elaborate. We could have $(i, j) < (i', j')$ and $(i', j') < (i, j'')$ where $j, j'$ and $j''$ are not necessarily related in any manner. If $\leq$ was antisymmetric the proof is clear but a direction need not be a partial order.

Comment: @KarthikKannan In that case $i < i'$ and $i' < i''$ so $i < i''$ and we're done.

Comment: @Henro, why do we have the strict inequality $i < i''$? The direction may not be antisymmetric. I don't know if I'm missing something trivial here.

Comment: @KarthikKannan $i \le i’’$ from transitivity. $ i = i’’$ cannot hold so $ i < i’’ $.

Comment: @henro that is exactly where I'm stuck. I am not able to show that $i = i'$ cannot hold. I have posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144198/proving-that-the-lexicographic-order-is-a-direction) with further details and the relevant definitions.